# CSS Transform Scale z-index

Tags: css, hover, scale, z-index

I'm trying to figure out how to bring the hover content from the section "some featured design works" on top of other tiles in that section.

Hover over the 400x400 image placeholders and you'd see the titles for these going underneath the other ones.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

As the tiles are inside different `"row"` `divs`, so no matter what `z-index` you apply, they will be stacked according to the parent `"row"` div order.

The `z-index` property is relative to the parent container. So a `z-index` of 100 in the 1st row will be under the `z-index` of 1 in the 2nd row

You can only fix this by putting all of the tiles inside the same `"row"` `div` and then then give a high `z-index` (something like 9999) to the hover style.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `z-index`:

```
.wordWrap:hover{
   ...
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From inspecting the code on the example you provided, it looks like each image has a negative `z-index:-999` then a `transform:scale(1.5);` is applied to the parent on hover.

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/bbetheldo/pen/GrGPvB)